# Prevent touchstart when page scrolling on mobile with ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, touchstart

Normally this would be the code:

```
var touchmoved;
$('button').on('touchend', function(e){
    if(touchmoved != true){
        // you're on button click action
    }
}).on('touchmove', function(e){
    touchmoved = true;
}).on('touchstart', function(){
    touchmoved = false;
});
```

However, this code doesn't seem to work for dynamically generated ajax elements.

For that, I have this code:

```
var touchmoved;
$(document).on('click touchend', '.menu', function(){
    if(touchmoved != true){
        // you're on button click action
    }
}).on('touchmove', '.menu', function(e){
    touchmoved = true;
}).on('touchstart', '.menu', function(){
    touchmoved = false;
});
```

Now it works for web interface but doesn't seem to work for mobile interface.

Is there a work arround that can be made so that I can make ajax calls dynamically and for it to work properly?

Comment: Anybody? I really haven't come across an answer for this. I will keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code I posted originally was the correct answer.

I was using a 3rd party script called nicescroll and it had some bugs in the version I had downloaded.

So for future generations, the way (for now) to prevent touchstart for dynamically generated elements is:

```
var touchmoved;
$(document).on('click touchend', '.menu', function(){
    if(touchmoved != true){
        // your click action here!!!
    }
}).on('touchmove', '.menu', function(e){
    touchmoved = true;
}).on('touchstart', '.menu', function(){
    touchmoved = false;
});
```